# Press Button automatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I press button one time. And after that i want press button automatically.
I try this code. But not working. Button variable name is ok.

```
VOID CALLBACK timerCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
    {
        CkTimerDlg *box = (CkTimerDlg *)AfxGetMainWnd();
        CString test = _T("Button Not Clicked");
        box->testBox1.AddString(test);

        HWND hwdButton = ::GetDlgItem(box->ok, IDOK);
        ::PostMessage(box->ok , WM_COMMAND, MAKELONG(IDOK, BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM)
    hwdButton);

    }

    void SomeFunc()
    {
        SetTimer(NULL, 1, 1000, timerCallback);

        /*MSG msg;

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }*/
    }


    void CkTimerDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
    {
        CString button = _T("Button Clicked");
        testBox1.AddString(button);
        SomeFunc();
    }
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget your `timerCallback` function

You need this:

In the class definition of `CkTimerDlg` add this méthod

```
void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent);
```

Add this method to the `CkTimerDlg` class:

```
void CTESTDLGDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent) 
{
    OnBnClickedOk();
    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

In the message map of `CkTimerDlg`:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTESTDLGDlg, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CTESTDLGDlg)
    ...
    ON_WM_TIMER()   // <-- add this
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

In `CkTimerDlg::OnInitDialog` add:

```
SetTimer(1,2000, NULL);   // will call OnTimer after 2000 milliseconds
```

You don't need to call `SetTimer`in `somefunc`.

Comment: Sir, Thank you. I solve my problem with the help of your code.